# how to make only one data set to be plotted with lines using JFreeChart?

Tags: java, dataset, jfreechart, scatter-plot

i have created a chart that plots two data sets.
i am trying to plot one of them as points and the other one as lines.
but it is not working. here is a picture of the chart:
[image]

here is my code where i generate the chart:

```
private ChartPanel createChartPanel() {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
            "", "Longitude [deg]", "Latitude [deg]", createSampleData(),
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        XYLineAndShapeRenderer render = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, true);
            xyPlot.setRenderer(0, render);

            XYLineAndShapeRenderer render2 = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(false, true);
            xyPlot.setRenderer(1, render2);
        return new ChartPanel(chart){
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(768, 576);
            }
        };
    }

    private XYDataset createSampleData() {
        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
            XYSeries Line_end_points = new XYSeries("Line end points");
            Line_end_points.add(new XYDataItem(startP.getX(), startP.getY()));
            Line_end_points.add(new XYDataItem(endP.getX(), endP.getY()));
            dataset.addSeries(Line_end_points);
        dataset.addSeries(pnts);       
        return dataset;
    }
```

as you can see i am creating two different renderers, but both data sets plotted as lines. what am i missing? any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: At a  minimum, you need _two_ datasets, one for each renderer; please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Answer (score 0):

solved my problem. changes some of the code in the `ChartPanel()` method:

```
private ChartPanel createChartPanel() {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
            "", "Longitude [deg]", "Latitude [deg]", createSampleData(),
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
            XYLineAndShapeRenderer render = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
            render.setSeriesLinesVisible(0, true);
            render.setSeriesShapesVisible(0, true);
            render.setSeriesLinesVisible(1, false);
            render.setSeriesShapesVisible(1, true);
            xyPlot.setRenderer(render);
        return new ChartPanel(chart){
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(768, 576);
            }
        };
    }
```